# How do i set up registration for multiple workshops?

Tags: civievent

I am trying to set up registration for an event that has multiple workshops. i need people to pre register and i am uncertain how to set up.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup workshops as price fields within a price set. Setup the field with your choices, make the price $0 & uncheck the 'Display amount' box. They will show up as line items on the registrant's receipt at $0 cost.

Another option is to make them custom fields for participants and add them to a profile.

I find reporting is more is more robust when you use fields in a price set.

Hope this helps.